# Difference between Firebase real-time database and Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

On the firebase console a Cloud Firestore tab has been added and going through the documentation it has some similar features like Realtime database. My android app already uses the Real-time database, functions, and storage and everything work fine. I would like to know how the Cloud Firestore can make my application better and what are the special features present only in Firestore that are not there in the real-time database that could improve my application.

I have a chat based application running on the real-time database and I am performing very frequent requests for small amount of data. Will switching to Firestore reduce my cost? Will it maintain or increases the speed of operation?

Comment: The [announcement blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/10/introducing-cloud-firestore.html) specifically has a link to the [in-depth comparision](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/10/cloud-firestore-for-rtdb-developers.html).

Answer (score 2):

A developer advocate answers in [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/10/cloud-firestore-for-rtdb-developers.html)

The main points:

- Better querying and more structured data
- Designed to Scale
- Easier manual fetching of data
- Multi-Region support for better reliability
- Different pricing model

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17519387)

Comment: Good point @l-l, I hate when I click a dead link in a SO answer

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud Firestore is an upgrade on the Real-time database although the Cloud Firestore is still in beta.

The Cloud Firestore offers

1. Better and faster data queries. With the C. Firestore, data at the top  collections can be fetched without grabbing any sub-collections in its children node. This prevents downloading unwanted data from your db unlike the real-time db.
2. Scalability: The above already explain why this is more scalable.No matter how large your db is, your app will only request for necessary data unlike the real-time db.

Read more: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore

Comment: For an ionic app would firestore be better. It is an app that will have a chat forum .